# Verificar se o usuário tem saldo/crédito

Tags: java, android

estou fazendo um app no qual preciso verificar se a pessoa possui crédito no celular. Queria saber como posso fazer isso. Mt obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Amigo... até onde eu entendo, o que você quer saber não é nada fácil.

**Primeiro**: cada operadora tem um método diferente de saber o saldo. A TIM e a Claro são por USSD (quando você disca um número começando por * e terminando por # e recebe uma mensagem ou um menu). A Vivo e a TIM tem SMS. E a Oi é apenas por mensagem de voz (como você vai "ouvir" uma mensagem de voz?)

Detalhe: as operadoras podem alterar o formato da mensagem, incluir informação de saldo promocional, ou até propagandas de outros serviços.

http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2015/12/saldo-vivo-tim-claro-oi-celular.html

**Segundo**: Isto tudo que tem acima é se o celular for pré-pago. E como você identifica se o celular é pré ou pós pago?

**Terceiro**: E existem outras operadoras: a Nextel, a Porto Seguro tem uma operadora própria, além de outras.

http://www.teleco.com.br/opcelular.asp

Não é impossível, mas vai ser bem complicado, além de poder alterar a qualquer momento.

Comment: Mt obrigado Plinio. Eu já esperava que fosse difícil msm, até pq não achei mt coisa na net, na real não achei nada. O problema é que no meu app eu verifico se o celular do usuário tá conectado no wifi, mas não se tem msm internet (tipo se a internet caiu). Vi umas ideias de tentar acessar uma pagina e dae me certificar de que tem msm internet, mas achei mt mão, e outra, quando o wifi ta desligado, se os dados tão ligados, no caso usar a internet por crédito, ele entende que tem internet, msm sem crédito, por isso a minha pergunta.

Comment: Mas vou dar meu jeito aqui, de uma forma mais simples, vou avisar o usuário e tals. Mt obrigado msm. Vlw por esclarecer!